# Container wont fit 100% of screen

Tags: css, html

I am trying to have a typical forum look to my website but the container of my content won't fit to 100% of my page height.

I have tried using `height: 100vh;` and all the others I can find.

My CSS is

```
body {
  font-family: Verdanna, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #f2efe8;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-image: url("../resources/bokeh.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  font-family: Verdanna, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

div.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

This is my webpage, with vertical overflow [image]

Comment: your question is not clear !!!!

Comment: share your html and replicate your problem in a snippet

Comment: Sorryyy, I rushed it. 
So basically I have a page with a container 
And i want that container background colour to be always black, and always fit 100% of screen vertically. 100vh works, 
But only to the screen height, If i scroll down, my content is outside of the container

Comment: Please don't post links to your website or images. Images can't be used to debug and links to your site are temporary and will make the question redundant ones the site changes. Try using the "snippet" feature to include a working demonstration of your problem of even a JSFiddle or similar. Also, have a look at this please [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: share your HTML please.

Answer (score 0):

If you add 100% height to the body & html and min-height: 100% to the container you'll be good to go (unless I've misunderstood the question).

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Full code example: https://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/ZKZeLz

Comment: This works, 
But the list from the image above still overhangs the container because its size is more than 100% of the screen, 
But what you said works on all pages without a scroll bar.

Comment: Apologies, that was an oversight on my part. min-height: 100% on the container should fix this?

Comment: Can you post the full HTML if possible and the CSS for the list, please? There must be something else interfering with this.

Comment: Is there any way I can message you personally? 
Stack wont let me post unless there is more text about my issue

Comment: Set up your code on https://codepen.io or https://jsfiddle.net/. Add the link to your question with a bit of text similar to: "Edit: Added additional code example". That should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

Create a wrapper with it's own id or class and set it with these css properties:

```
.background {
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   color: #f2efe8;
   background-image: url("../resources/bokeh.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   z-index:-1;
}
```

This content will never scroll though.

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/6q2v5o8o/)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you should want the page to be at least 100% height, but still increase if more content are added.

```
html, body{
  height: auto; /* This is applied by default, so it's not necessary to define it */
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Here I use `min-height: 100vh` instead of `min-height: 100%` because otherwise the body will not take 100%, because the parent needs a fixed height for that.

Then, when you want a full screen container, don't try with `height: 100%`, you can create a helper class for that:

```
.vh-100{
    height: 100vh;
}
```